# How to insert JSON Data from URL to ListView in NativeScript-Vue

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

I have trouble insert JSON Data from API to ListView. 
Here is the link API : https://webservicevsid.com/API/GetEvent.php

I am using NativeScript-Vue for this Project

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like Ajax, jQuery, or Axios to fetch the data. [Here](https://www.sitepoint.com/fetching-data-third-party-api-vue-axios/) is an example of what you are looking for with Axios. Basically, include a script with a link to an external file that can handle this logic.

index.html

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

then, in your view include something like ...

```
mounted() {
  axios.get("https://webservicevsid.com/API/GetEvent.php")
  .then(response => {this.results = response.data.results})
}
```

Im not too familiar with NativeScript but, [this](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2018/07/02/vue-js-native-script-vue-http-web-service/) may be more what your looking for ...

```
<script>
  import axios from "axios";
  export default {
  data() {
    return {
      data: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    axios({ method: "GET", "url": 
    "https://webservicevsid.com/API/GetEvent.php" }).then(result => {
      this.data = result.data.results;
    }, error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may just use axios or Http module to hit the api and load the response into list view.

```
<template>
    <Page class="page">
        <ActionBar title="Home" class="action-bar" />
        <ListView for="item in listOfItems" class="list-group">
            <v-template>
                <!-- Shows the list item label in the default color and style. -->
                <Label :text="item.nama_event" class="list-group-item" />
            </v-template>
        </ListView>
    </Page>
</template>

<script>
    const axios = require("axios");

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                listOfItems: []
            };
        },
        mounted: function() {
            axios
                .get("https://webservicevsid.com/API/GetEvent.php")
                .then(response => {
                    this.listOfItems = response.data;
                });
        }
    };
</script>
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=5UZdiH)